# IntelliJ Wide Analysis Tools declares a duplicated class for a class generated by OpenAPI, while CLI compiles everything well, and IntelliJ also

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My project declares some business objects.
At a time, after they've been used in some services, these services and objects are exposed, through REST with *OpenAPI*.

Sources created by the *OpenAPI* generator are, of course, created in *target*, with the `@Generated` annotation: the "official generator" creates them for me.

And everything is working fine:

- console maven compilation works,
- *Rebuild Project* works,
- Application is running fine...

But then I've sat then the *Project : Wide analysis tool* in action. It complains:

`Duplicate class found in the file '/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/src/main/scala/fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/model/Commune.scala'`

Yes, `Commune.scala` produces a `Commune.class` in its *target* folder,
while the original object, `Commune.java`, is also doing the same it its own `ObjetsMetiers` project, earlier.

But that's normal: that's the goal of *OpenAPI*...

I tried to search among *Project Structure* what could cause the problem, but without success.

*IntelliJ* is often too clever and complex, especially when it comes to understand *Maven* projects. It mixes and lose itself, it's incredible.

[image]

Comment: You could try to right click the `xxx/swagger/scala` in the output folder, and choose the `Mark Directory as | Excluded` to exclude that Scala output folder to avoid this warning.

Comment: @LJreplica the problem was then solved, but eventually I discovered that I should have done an "_Inspect Code_" (from menu) to get the analysis I was willing to achieve!